# Google universal analytics

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I would like to set up google universal analytics for my desktop application. In this case ,  should I set up the account with " all web site data " , but feed data through measurement protocol . Will this work ? because I see that when you say all web site data , it asks for website url etc ..

Comment: You could always simply try :-) But yes, as far as I can tell this works, we have implemented this a couple if times and the results look good. The domain name in the configuration has largely decorative purposes in any case.

Comment: It worked. question related to custom dimension and metrics for desktop app. Do I need to associate custom dimension and metric to an event while sending data ? because otherwise I am unable to send data..  This request is associated with event which logs data in google analytics , works.. url += "?v=1&tid=UA-xxx-1&cid=555&t=event&ec=video&ea=play&el=holiday&ev=300&cd2=desktop" ; But below request does not work..
   url += "?v=1&tid=UA-XXX-&cid=555&cd2=VisualStudio" ;

Comment: Yes. Custom dimensions and metrics need an interaction hit (pageview,event,transaction,item or timing) to be transmitted to the server.

Comment: Got it , thank you.. Hmm so it is different for IOS. Per iOS SDK  you send custom dimension without sending hittype ( but it gets assocaited with the hit scope defined during creation of the dimension/metric )

Comment: Is is possible to send page tracking info with custom dimensions ? because the below example does not work .
url += "?v=1&tid=UA-XXX-1&cid=555&&t=pageview&dh=mydemo.com&dp=/home&dt=homepage&cd2=VisualStudio2" ;

Comment: Sending page traking info does not seem to work . Any help http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-48993606-1&cid=555&t=pageview&sc=start&dh=mydemocom&dp=home&dt=homepage